# nginx reverse proxy upstream initial connection very slow

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Using nginx for reverse proxying the http requests between openshift services. Nginx itself is deployed on openshift as well;

```
 upstream my_servers {
        server service1.svc:49253;
        server service2.svc:49253;
        server service3.svc:49253;
      }

location ~ /myservice1 {
                   proxy_pass  https://service1.svc:49253;
                   proxy_http_version 1.1;
                   proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                   proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                   proxy_send_timeout          600;
                   proxy_read_timeout          600;
                   send_timeout                600;
                 }
location ~ /myservice2 {
                   proxy_pass  https://service2.svc:49253;
                   proxy_http_version 1.1;
                   proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                   proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                   proxy_send_timeout          600;
                   proxy_read_timeout          600;
                   send_timeout                600;
                 }
location ~ /myservice3 {
                   proxy_pass  https://service3.svc:49253;
                   proxy_http_version 1.1;
                   proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                   proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                   proxy_send_timeout          600;
                   proxy_read_timeout          600;
                   send_timeout                600;
                 }
location / {
                   proxy_pass  https://node_servers; 
                   proxy_http_version 1.1;
                   proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;       
                   proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                   proxy_send_timeout          600;
                   proxy_read_timeout          600;
                   send_timeout                600;                           
                 }
```

final **/location** block will always receive only http requests while the first three will receive both http and ws requests. So, I didn't put **http_upgrade** parts in this final block, I just want /location block to **upstream my_servers**.

The problem here is, this final /location block upstreams the http requests, but very slow! When a http request is not upstreamed, i.e., uses first three location blocks, there is no problem.

How can I make the upstream faster?